# delete specific index of array based onClick in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a row consisting of a textbox and a button.

These rows can be added after clicking add new row button with the following code:

1. useState:
   `const [newSertifikasi, setNewSertifikasi] = useState(0)`
2. Load a row:
   `...Array(newSertifikasi).map((i) => ("components here"))`
3. Adds a new row:
   `onClick={() => setNewSertifikasi(newSertifikasi + 1)}`

I want to create a method of deleting rows by clicking on a button that is in a particular row.

I have used the "splice" and "filter" methods, but found a dead end

Here's the full code: https://codepen.io/febry-aryo-riandhito/pen/BaRpNKQ

Comment: add your full code or a sandbox in order to help you better

Comment: Here's the code: https://codepen.io/febry-aryo-riandhito/pen/BaRpNKQ

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the element by it index using `splice` like this, the function could be shorter but for sake of understanding this is a good solution.

```
function deleteByIndex(index){
     setNewSertifikasi(current => {
         const newArr = current;
         newArr.splice(index, 0);
         return newArr;
      })
}
```

a shorter version could be this

```
function deleteByIndex(index){
     setNewSertifikasi(current => [...current.splice(index, 1)])
}
```

Comment: How to the function could be shorter?

Comment: i've edited the answer you can take a look

Comment: there's an error: "TypeError: current.splice is not a function or its return value is not iterable". I place it after return component

Comment: well that happens the first time because your state is a number not an array at the initialization so change it to empty array would fix the problem  `const [newSertifikasi, setNewSertifikasi] = useState([])`

Comment: please send your code in a pen so we can assist you better i gave you the idea not the implementation

Comment: Here's the code: https://codepen.io/febry-aryo-riandhito/pen/BaRpNKQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234821/discussion-between-febry-aryo-and-kak-sarkar).

Comment: Error is same as I give the error in previous comment

Answer (score -1):

```
let test = ['test01', 'test02', 'test03']

test.splice(1,1); // this delete specific index

console.log(test) // ['test01', 'test03']
```